# default user of postgres at install

Tags: postgresql

I installed Postgres on Windows 7, it only asks me for password not for username so what's the default. It is said here:

> When Postgres is installed in your account, there is a default user with the same name as the account (login) name

It's not crystal clear. Is it the username of my computer account?

Comment: Sure sounds like it. What happens when you try and use it?

Comment: Except it seems not see answer below

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I don't know what installer have you used but when I install it the username is clearly indicated:

[image: Postres' setup, password step]

Answer (score 18):

"postgres" is the default user name

Answer (score 3):

Though It is an old question, I would like to put my answer.

Default Username of PostgreSQL on Windows is **postgres**.